# How to automatically uncheck a checkbox if the textbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, textbox

I'm building a donation form.

If a checkbox with a fixed amount is checked by the user, I would like it to automatically uncheck if next the user clicks the textbox to insert a custom amount.

It would be important that the textbox would also clear if after inserting a custom amount the user opted to check a checkbox with a fixed amount.

I know nothing of JavaScript. Will someone help me achieve this?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="louzanimalespaypal@gmail.com">

    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5.00"><span>€05.00</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5.00"><span>€10.00</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5.00"><span>€15.00</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="amount" class="checkbutton" value="5.00"><span>€20.00</span>
<br>
    <strong>Other Amount</strong><br>
    $ <input type="text" class="TextBox" name="amount">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="Louzanimales_Donation_WPS_PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.louzanimales.py/agradecimentos.htm">

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal!">

</form>
```

**[UPDATE]**

I've put together the flowing which does exactly what I need.
If anyone thinks this can be improved, I would appreciate it:

```
$('input.checkbutton').on('change', function() {
    $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});

$(".textBox").focus(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").prop("checked", false );
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").change(function() {
        if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
            $('.textBox').val("");
        } 
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/28q8w3L8/3/)**

Comment: "I know nothing of JavaScript." — So [learn the language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) or [hire a freelancer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hire+a+javascript+freelancer&t=hv&ia=web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at you're updated answer I would do the follow:

```js
$('input.checkbutton').on('change', function() {
  $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if ($("input.checkbutton-other").val()) {
    $("input.checkbutton-other").val("");
  }
});

$("input.checkbutton-other").on("focus click", function() {
  $("input.checkbutton").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-group {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

label.cb-label {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}

label.cb-label:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: #fff;
}

label.cb-label span {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
}

label.cb-label input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.cb-label input:checked + span {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" target="_blank">
  <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
    <label for="cb5" class="cb-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="amount" id="cb5" class="checkbutton" value="5.00">
      <span>&#x80;05.00</span>
    </label>
    <label for="cb10" class="cb-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="amount" id="cb10" class="checkbutton" value="10.00">
      <span>&#x80;10.00</span>
    </label>
    <label for="cb15" class="cb-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="amount" id="cb15" class="checkbutton" value="15.00">
      <span>&#x80;15.00</span>
    </label>
    <label for="cb20" class="cb-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="amount" id="cb20" class="checkbutton" value="20.00">
      <span>&#x80;20.00</span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbOther"><strong>Any Amount</strong> &#x24;</label>
    <input type="number" name="amount" id="cbOther" class="checkbutton-other">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="WPS_PT">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="#">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay with PayPal!">
  </div>
</form>
```

I started by removing this JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkbutton").change(function() {
        if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
            $('.textBox').val("");
        }
    });
});
```

And replacing this code with:

```
$('input.checkbutton').on('change', function() {
  $('input.checkbutton').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if ($("input.checkbutton-other").val()) {
    $("input.checkbutton-other").val("");
  }
});
```

After changing the JavaScript I would update your HTML (codes like `&#x80;` are found on [Character-Code.com](http://character-code.com/currency-html-codes.php)):

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;"></div> // this html around the check boxes so their float don't affect other elements of page

<label for="cb5" class="cb-label"> // add `for` to the labels which can be tied to a `id` of the input it is related too and added a `class` for the css to be attached too
```

After the HTML update their was some CSS updates required. I'd remove the padding from the body and added this class instead:

```
.form-group {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

This class would be added to a `div` which would wrap your inputs. Also on your fancy checkbox css I added the class `.cb-label` so it won't effect other labels.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @DavidMartins I updated my answer to reflect your update on the question. Would've updated sooner, but holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, pure javascript

```
<input type='checkbox' id='my-check' />
<input type='text' id='my-text' onfocus='uncheck()' />

<script>
    function uncheck() {
        document.getElementById('my-check').checked = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use vanilla js this will be the perfect way to go.